# Import/ export data from sqllite database

Tags: android, sqlite

My question is more related to programming approach should be used to import/ export data from SQLLite database.

I'm new to android APP development and developing a simple notepad application where in I want to give an option to user to export & import notes to/from a file.

I've done quite research on web and found there are various way to do that:

1. Write data from database to a file in CSV format - probably using OpenCSV library
2. Write data from database to a file in XML format
3. take backup of SQLLite db file itself and replace it while importing - I believe this approach won't let me keep my old notes and import the notes from backup db file?

I would like to know which approach would be better. If there anything else which is better than above ones would like to know about it.

Comment: I'd say **1**, but without using 3rd party libraries (it's so easy to import and export a comma delimited file!!). You can then use the REPLACE INTO command, which updates existing data and inserts new one, if the row is not existing. OR 2. But xml files are bloated with garbage tags... and it's more complicated to parse them.

Comment: @Vyger: Shouldn't you post that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say **1**, but without using 3rd party libraries (it's so easy to import and export a comma delimited file!!).
You can then use the REPLACE INTO command, which updates existing data and inserts a new one, if the row is not existing.

OR even **2**.
But xml files are bloated with garbage tags... and it's more complicated to parse them then reading/writing simple text files (with or without header row).